# Amazon Kendra and Botpress

Tags: amazon-kendra

I am trying to integrate my Botpress (Chatbot) with Kendra. So that when a user types a query it will trigger the Kendra and give the results. I have created the s3, Index & Experience. I am getting the response on Kendra experience. But I want to connect my Kendra with a chatbot whose backend is Node.js. In my bot I have to make connections and in the Kendra documentation there is nothing I found to make a connection to my Kendra.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon LEX has a native offering for integrating with Kendra - https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/integrate-amazon-kendra-and-amazon-lex-using-a-search-intent/.

For other chatbots, you need to build the integration using AWS SDKs.